# How to display data from mysql as a piechart using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql

I want to display the club name and the number of children from the table below in a piechart

[image: This is the table form mysql]

Here is the behind code for the PieChart webform I have created:

```
public partial class PieChart : System.Web.UI.Page
```

{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


string club_name;
int no_children;

public int TargetClub_No()

{


    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbyouthworkConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(CS))
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT no_children, club_name FROM pie_chart WHERE club_name = 'Target Club'", con);



        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

            club_name = rdr["club_name"].ToString();
            no_children = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["no_children"]);

        }
          return no_children;

    }


}
```

}

I have already downloaded the js.chart file and jquery file

Here is the code in the PieChart.aspx file I have created :

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <canvas id="mycanvas" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ctx = $("#mycanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
        // pie chart data

        var t = <% TargetClub_No(); %>; 
        var data = [
        {
            value: t,
            color: "cornflowerblue",
            highlight: "lightskyblue",
            label: "Target Club"
        },
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "lightgreen",
            highlight: "yellowgreen",
            label: "Lightgreen"
        },
        {
            value: 40,
            color: "orange",
            highlight: "darkorange",
            label: "Orange"
        }

        ];


        //draw
        var piechart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
    });
</script>

<div>

</div>
</form>
```

*Here I have firstly tried to input the number of children from target club however when I run the code I get a blank page instead of a pie chart

SCREEN SHOTS USING DEV TOOLS IN CHROME:
This one shows that I have done something wrong in calling 'public int TargetClub_No()'
[image]

Here is the screen shot of the networks tab:
[image]

Not sure what this tab means though...

Comment: Hey Sonia, if you're using chrome the inbuilt dev tools are great at helping out issues like this. Specifically the network tab, do you have any output from there?

Comment: So I had a look at this and I have added screenshots above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there are syntax errors in your JS.. 
This portion:

```
var t = '<% TargetClub_No(); %>' 
//var data = [
```

should look like this:

```
var t = <%= TargetClub_No() %>;
var data = [
```

Now your C# method TargetClub_No() needs to return a value to assign to t. 
For what you are trying to do at first you want to return the number of children from target club. Like this:

```
public int TargetClub_No()
{
    ...
    //nothing else needs to change
    ...

    return no_children;
}
```

Eventually you will probably want your method TargetClub_No() to return all of the data in a way that you can assign it to data directly.

Here is an article that does exactly what you want (and a little more):
[Chart.js Asp.net : Create Pie chart with database jQuery Ajax C#](http://codepedia.info/2015/04/chartjs-asp-net-create-pie-chart-with-database-calling-jquery-ajax-c/)

Comment: I have changed the code but I still get a blank page with no pie chart appearing

Comment: I think I messed up the syntax around the line you mentioned above. Try `<%= TargetClub_No()  %>;`